# issue writing children in a @OneToMany JPA relationship from JHipster

Tags: jpa, jhipster, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I am tryng to do a workaround for this issue, that I have entered: 
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9639

I did some work (I added findAllWithEagerRelationships in the repository), and the GET method works fine: I get all the master and children.

What is not working, and I need your help, is the POST method: 
when I post a `parent` with some children (pets), the children are not posted with the parent, so children are lost.
so summarizing this is the get result, correct:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1002,
    "name": "Piera",
    "pets": [
      {
        "id": 1051,
        "name": "fido",
        "species": "barboncino",
        "owner": {
          "id": 1002,
          "name": "Piera"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

but the post does not work correctly:

```
{
  "name": "newName",
  "pets": [
    {
      "id": 1051
    }
  ]
}
```

newName is created, but pet 1051 is not attached to it

I am working on a app generated with Jhipster:

```
entity Owner {
    name String required
}

entity Pet {
    name String required,
    species String required
}

relationship OneToMany {
    Owner{pet} to Pet{owner}
}
```

for the get, I added those two methods that I copied form a `manytomany` relationship, and they worked:

```
@Query(value = "select distinct owner from Owner owner left join fetch owner.pets")
List<Owner> findAllWithEagerRelationships();

@Query("select owner from Owner owner left join fetch owner.pets where owner.id =:id")
Optional<Owner> findOneWithEagerRelationships(@Param("id") Long id);
```

```java
    Public class Owner implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Pet> pets = new HashSet<>();
    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
```

```java
    public class Pet implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "species", nullable = false)
    private String species;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("pets")
    private Owner owner;

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
```

I expect that when I do a post on a parent with some children, the children (pets) are also posted.

Comment: so the changes you want to see are not in the DB? does the children and parents are saved to the M2M table?

Comment: the changes that I want are already in the DB (as it is created by Jhipster), and the childrend and parents are saved in the DATABASE (as shown below) .....but I have some issue to render this structure in the JAVA/JPA code.
Pls find the DB structure (created for me by JHIPSTER): 


CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC.PET(
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    SPECIES VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    OWNER_ID BIGINT
)
CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC.OWNER(
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)

Comment: I assume you are using DTOs. Check the corresponding DTO, there are some fields that marked as `ignore`, delete/comment that line and it should work

Comment: Hello, I did not use DTO but, after your suggestion, I tried: , and  there was no felds marked as ignore there – so I believen your suggestion did not work.

Also, as reported above, there is a   @JsonIgnoreProperties("pets") in the class Pet, but if I remove it I get a: Infinite recursion exception

Comment: that's why it's a good idea to use DTOs so you don't have infinite loops and also you don't transfer information that you actually wouldn't need. Anyways, if your field doesn't get populated, try doing it so in the service layer using the parent id.

Comment: sorry I don't understand your suggestion. anyway I believe we should resolve the question in JPA: if the DTO is not populated with childs, we can't do anything. So I would appreciate a lot a JPA solution

Answer (score 0):

In your `Owner` service interface and implementation layer (it should be under `com.yourpackage.service` and `com.yourpackage.service.impl`) create a new method like

```java
public Optional<Owner> findOneWithChildren(long id) {
   Optional<Owner> owner = ownerRepository.findById(id);
   owner.ifPresent(o -> {
       o.getPets().addAll(petRepository.getByParentId(id);
   }
   return owner.map(ownerMapper::toDto);
}
```

And in your `Pet` repository, create a new method, like

```java
List<Pet> getByParentId(long id);
```

Comment: thanks but this does not answer my question. I was not looking for a code to write owners and pet, not to query them. 
I already have two working methods for this: findAllWithEagerRelationships() and findOneWithEagerRelationships (), that I reported in the code above.

Comment: oh, I see what you meant, sorry

Answer (score 0):

in the bug report, I could find a workaround without touching the JPA. I still don't know how we can put a new owner associating to it some pets with JPA as I did receive a resolving answer, anyway my workaround works. thanks :)